# What's the difference between 「adb logcat」in terminal and executing「Runtime.getRuntime.exec(“logcat”)」in apps?

Tags: android, linux, logging, logcat

One way is to show logs in Windows cmd, and another is to print in the app. What's the differences(or range？) of logs i get because they are all logs from the system.
And I also noticed that the logs in cmd here have four different types like "beginning of main""beginning of kernel""beginning of system" which I don't get in the second way. What are they？

Comment: Did you find a reason? They are indeed very different on my Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, they are both the same.
But actually, you could input `adb logcat "*:E"` into your console to filter ERROR (the prefix as 'E/') level logs.
Plus, 'V' for VERBOSE, 'D' for DEBUG, 'I' for INFO, 'W' for WARN, 'A' for ASSERT.